# codeigniter send input file info via ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, upload

I have a form with 4 fields: title, price, image and category.

When submitted, it inserts the 3 strings into the DB and uploads the image, or returns errors. It all works fine.

However, now I want it to be done via ajax.

It works fine for the title, price and category fields, but how do I pass the info needed from the file field so that codeigniter can upload it?

Right now it keeps saying "You did not select a file to upload."

My controller:

```
function add_new_product_ajax() 
    {
        // make sure it's the admin, else redirect
        if ( ! $this->session->userdata('is_admin') ) {
            redirect('admin/login'); 
            exit();
        }

        // get product name
        $pn = $this->input->post('product_title');

        // get price 
        $p = $this->input->post('price');

        // get category id 
        $cid = $this->input->post('categories');

        // upload config
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $config['overwrite']  = TRUE;

        // load form validation
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // validate fields
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('product_title', 'Product Name', 'trim|required|is_unique[products.name]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'trim|required|callback_check_price');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('categories', 'Product\'s Category', 'required');

         // if validation failed
        if ($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) 
        {   
            // dummy var
            $data['dummy'] = '';

            // load categories module to make a select list
            $this->load->module('categories/categories');
            $data['options'] = $this->categories->categories_select();

            // load the view        
            $this->load->view('new_product_view', $data);        
        }
        else // validation passed
        {
            // do upload
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $field_name = "userfile";
            // $this->upload->do_upload($field_name);

            // try to upload 
            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()) {

                $data['error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();

                // load categories module to make a select list
                $this->load->module('categories/categories');
                $data['options'] = $this->categories->categories_select();

                // load the view        
                $this->load->view('new_product_view', $data);        

            } 
            else // upload successful, insert data into table 
            {
                // insert product data 
                $this->mdl_products->add_product($pn, $p, $cid);

                // success msg
                $data['msg'] = '<div class=successmsg>The product has been added!</div>'; 

                // load categories module to make a select list
                $this->load->module('categories/categories');
                $data['options'] = $this->categories->categories_select();

                // load the view        
                $this->load->view('new_product_view', $data);        
            }

        }

    }
```

My ajax ( with missing file value parameter):

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.submitnewprod', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // alert('code');return;

        // get product title 
        var pt = $('#product_title').val();

        // get product price 
        var pp = $('#price').val();

        // get category id 
        var cid = $('#categories').val();

        // get userfile ???????
        var uf = $('#uploadImage').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: site + "admin/add-new-product-ajax",
            data: { 
                product_title:pt,
                price: pp,
                categories: cid
            },

            beforeSend: function() {
                 $('#ajaximg img').addClass('act');
            },

            success: function(data) {
                // $('.results').html(data);
                $('#ajax').html(data);
            },

            complete: function() {
                 $('#ajaximg img').removeClass('act');
            }

        });


    });
```

the file html from my view file:

```
<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="userfile" size="20" onchange="PreviewImage();" />
```

What do I need to pass in my ajax call inside `data` parameter, so that the upload can work normally?

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue in your PHP its to do with how you are posting the $_FILE field. Instead of grabbing individual form fields try using the form serialize function of jQuery and declare the post as `multipart/form-data`. There is loads of examples of how to achieve this on SO but should look a bit like this...

```
       var myData = $('#your_form').serialize(); 
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            contentType:attr( "enctype", "multipart/form-data" ),
            url: " URL Goes Here ",  
            data: myData
            ...
```